# GsonFromJson: how to serialize and de serialize with array structures

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Im working on a project where we used jsonfile as its database  since SQLite doesnt meet the requirement. The project has a portion when an object fron the wordbank is use it will change the status(such as 1-4). I made use of JSONArray to access the data. When i tried to change/edit the status, it doesnt save or write back to the jsonfile. Instead it only works on the momentary use of the application.

From searches, alot of stuff pop out that using gson. I concluded to use gson.

I am new to gson and just started learning it the other day. And i am having troubles with it.

This is the structure of my jsonfile. It has 2 objects(users and wordbank) that are arrayed

```
{ 
"users" :
  [{
    "username": "free",
    "password": "free",
    "email": "free@gmail.com",
    "type": "1"
  },
  {
    "username": "premium",
    "password": "premium",
    "email": "premium@gmail.com",
    "type": "2"
  }],
"wordbank" : 
  [{
      "English": "able",
      "Cebuano": "kaya",
      "Pronunciation": "ká-ya",
      "POS": "adjective",
      "Audio": "kaya.mp3",
      "Status": "0"
  },
  {
      "English": "advice",
      "Cebuano": "tambag",
      "Pronunciation": "tam-bag",
      "POS": "noun",
      "Audio": "tambag.mp3",
      "Status": "0"
  }]
}
```

From what I've seen in tutorial videos is that you create a different java class for its model. So i create 3 java class. user, wordbank and dictionary (combining them both).

```
public class dictionary{
  users[] user;
  wordbanks[] word;
}
```

Im using an existing jsonfile already so i parsed it and got its jsonstring. After which i tried to deserialize it using

```
jsonstring = readFromFile();//returns string from jsonfile
dictionary list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonstring, dictionary.class);
```

runned it and debug it. but when i got the results. it was null.

QUESTIONS:
1.Will I be able to edit and save the changes in json file by using gson? 
2.Is my structure correct for the distionary class?
3.how to serialize and deserialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If your member variables of pojo Classes(users,workdbank,dictionary) don't match with JSON key, consider using @SerializedName provided by GSON.  In your case, i was able to deserialise the string using gson by using @SerializedName as shown below

User Class

```
 public class User {

       @SerializedName("username")
    private String userName;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    // Add Getters and Setters
}
```

WordBank Class

```
public class Wordbank {

    @SerializedName("English")
    private String english;
    @SerializedName("Cebuano")
    private String cebuano;
    @SerializedName("Pronunciation")
    private String pronunciation;
    @SerializedName("POS")
    private String pos;
    @SerializedName("Audio")
    private String audio;
    @SerializedName("Status")
    private String status;

    // Add getters and Setters
}
```

Dictionary Class

```
    public class Dictonary {

    @SerializedName("users")
    User[] userArray;
    @SerializedName("wordbank")
    Wordbank[] wordbankArray;

    public User[] getUserArray() {
        return userArray;
    }

    public void setUserArray(User[] userArray) {
        this.userArray = userArray;
    }

    public Wordbank[] getWordbankArray() {
        return wordbankArray;
    }

    public void setWordbankArray(Wordbank[] wordbankArray) {
        this.wordbankArray = wordbankArray;
    }
}
```

After making necessary changes as explained above, I was able to deserialise the string

```
 Dictonary dictonary =  new Gson().fromJson(input,Dictonary.class);
```

Comment: This helped me to get to arrive to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `Gson` for all your requirements. First create matching Pojo for your json structure. you can use tools such as [this pojo generator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Just paste the json there (don't select json schema) and generate. Assuming you have three classes `Result` (contains to lists, similar to your dictionary class), `User` and `Wordbank` class. You can read (deserialize) and write (serialize) back into a file as follows.

```
try {
    // deserialize
    Result result = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(new File("src/test/resources/sample.json")), Result.class);
    // ... update result as required
    // result.users.remove(0);
    // serialize
    String json = gson.toJson(result);
    Files.write(new File("src/test/resources/sample.json").toPath(), json.getBytes());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: new FileReader(new File("src/test/resources/sample.json")) a string or a jsonfile?

Comment: That is the path to the json file, not the json string. `String json = gson.toJson(result);` statement convert object to json string, `json` variable holds that json string, next line writes that string to the file specified